# Most ugly web applications around

Tags: web-applications

What are some ugly web applications around (other than StackOverflow, obviously :)  )?

By ugly I mean the graphic look of the app (or deep UX flaws).
Just looking for some examples.

Comment: Ugly is subjective, what are you getting at?

Comment: not sure if trolling or...

Comment: Define ugly?  Coding wide, load time, graphical design?  Just a poorly conceived question.  After all you can google and find many apps.

Comment: Ugly as in graphical design. I'll edit the question. I've googled "ugly web app" and didn't see anything.

Comment: Is this an attempt of getting a question closed in the shortest time on [SO], or did you just leave your workstation unlocked and logged in to [SO] with some prankster colleagues around?

Comment: OBVIOUSLY, when I mentioned StackOverflow, I was kidding...

Comment: @ppeterka: Do you want to reply with http://allware.hu/ or should I? :)

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth Wow, you have done research, I like that :) That was an experiment (actually, as visible, pretty much gone wrong) - I agree that I'm not much of a designer (and I was nice and easy :) ). (to explain, I wanted to try out if I can make the content part go under the header, by providing a transparent PNG). But I'm curious, as to why you didn't mention ppeterka.hu, as I'm not happy with that either, and that is directly linked into my profile...

Comment: @ppeterka: Actually, I don't think ppeterka.hu is that horrible.

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth wow, I never expected to have such heartwarming words about my "work" (haha) as a "designer"... I take this as a serious compliment, my ego just received a huge boost. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the opposite of [zombo.com](http://www.zombo.com)

zombo.com is awesome, you can do anything at zombo.com.
anything at all.